# React Native: filling form without use of state (stateless form)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a form, inside a scrollview. there are few questions in the form, for example starrating or datepicker. See the code :

```js
<DatePicker
            date={this.state.currentDate}
            mode="date"
            placeholder="select date"
            format="DD-MM-YYYY"
            minDate="01-01-2015"
            maxDate="01-01-2050"
            confirmBtnText={I18n.t("confirm_button")}
            cancelBtnText={I18n.t("login_page_scan_cancel")}
            onDateChange={(date) => {this.setState({currentDate: date})}}
          />
```

As you see in code above, when you change value, it updates this.state.currentDate , and it also shows this.state.currentDate as current selected date. it's working, but the problem is when scroll down to fill the form, when you change the value, setState is being called, and since state is changing, component will update. it means it will go up. you will need to scroll down again.

How can i fix this? how can i store data temporary without using State?

is it possible when 'onDateChange' in DatePicker is being triggered, to change 'date' value in DatePicker?

Thanks in advance!

---

UPDATE:

I've found this http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/faq/ReactNative.md/ , stateless form management for react. as they say, its supporting react-native but i didn't find any example for react-native. can somebody please give an example?

Comment: what do you mean by store temporary?

Comment: @PeterGelderbloem store data temporary to submit it when user finished filling the form.

Comment: With react, you store it in state

Comment: @PeterGelderbloem , i know, my question was that. is it any other way instead of saving it to state? because when you save it to save component is re-rendering.

Comment: You can use mobx to store state outside the react component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to neglect whole screen to be re-rendered you have to make **component based design**.

You need to create your own **date picker component**. If you do so **only picker component will be rerendered** not whole screen.

---

How will I let my main component know currentDate ?

---

- You can add a prop called callback in your yourSpecialDatePicker component to inform your main component that date value is changed.

In example this.currDate value is used to assign date to value in main component but you don't have to. You can use a global variable or you do nothing it is up to you.  Most important thing is here is component based approach.

```
var datePicker = require/filepath .. /yourSpecialDatePicker)`;

    class yourMainComponent extends Component {
     constructor(props) {
           super(props);
           this.state = { };
           this.currDate='';
          }

     render() {
       return (
        <ScrollView>
          <datePicker callBack ={(value)=>{this.currDate=value}}></datePicker>
        </ScrollView>           
       )
     }
    }

class yourSpecialDatePicker extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {currentDate:'' };
  }

  render() {
    return (
   <DatePicker
            date={this.state.currentDate}
            mode="date"
            placeholder="select date"
            format="DD-MM-YYYY"
            minDate="01-01-2015"
            maxDate="01-01-2050"
            confirmBtnText={I18n.t("confirm_button")}
            cancelBtnText={I18n.t("login_page_scan_cancel")}
            onDateChange={(date) => {this.setState({currentDate: date})
                                     this.props.callBack(date)}}
          />
    );
  }
}
```